# Haskell: Using in-memory sqlite db in Yesod Tests?

Tags: sqlite, haskell, yesod-test

I'm trying to make my first Yesod website, and was now adding tests.

I'm setting up like this:

```
shortblitoWebServerSpec :: ShortblitoWebServerSpec -> Spec
shortblitoWebServerSpec =
  yesodSpecWithSiteGenerator $
    runNoLoggingT $
      withSqlitePool ":memory:" 1 $ \pool -> do
        let app =
              App
                { appLogLevel = LevelWarn,
                  appStatic = shortblitoWebServerStatic,
                  appConnectionPool = pool,
                  appGoogleAnalyticsTracking = Nothing,
                  appGoogleSearchConsoleVerification = Nothing
                }
        _ <- runSqlPool (runMigrationQuiet migrateTables) pool
        pure app
```

And have some tests:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = shortblitoWebServerSpec $
  ydescribe "ShortenerR" $ do
    yit "Home page exists" $ do
      get ShortenerR
      statusIs 200
    yit "Post to shorten" $ do
      postBody ShortenerR "test"
      statusIs 200
```

When I run that I get the following error:

`11/Jun/2021:14:52:15 +0200 [Error#yesod-core] SQLite3 returned ErrorError while attempting to perform prepare "SELECT \"id\",\"long\" FROM \"url\" WHERE \"long\"=?": no such table: url @(yesod-core-1.6.18-Ab7hNtiUzJgGsCLpKcpJyh:Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod src/Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs:688:5)`

However, when I change the `:memory:` to `test.db` the tests run fine.

So somewhere the in-memory db gets lost. But I'm not sure how to prevent that.

How do I solve this? So I can use an in-memory db for testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`withSqlitePool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3/docs/Database-Persist-Sqlite.html#v:withSqlitePool) mentions:

> Like [`createSqlitePool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3/docs/Database-Persist-Sqlite.html#v:createSqlitePool), this should not be used with :memory:.

The documentation of `createSqlitePool` mentions:

> Note that this should not be used with the :memory: connection string, as the pool will regularly remove connections, destroying your database. Instead, use [`withSqliteConn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3/docs/Database-Persist-Sqlite.html#v:withSqliteConn).

I don't know enough about Yesod and your exact use case to give more help.